# scrolling in custom control content - xpages

Tags: css, xpages

My `layout_main` custom control contains 3 tops `layout_banner`s, one custom control ( facet ) which contains  the custom control for the document called `ccDoc`, and one layout_footer. This `layout_main` is on my `xmain` XPage.

Is there any chance to 'enable' scrolling for my `ccDoc.`? Its structure is quite big, having numerous fields, and if its size > window size, the entire xpage ( window ) is scrolling and I found my lowest banner/layout_footer not visible on the window browser - I must scroll down to see it. I want just the`ccDoc` to have the scrolling possibility and the others custom controls / layouts to stay fixed.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Surround your content in ccDoc with a div with a fixed height and overflow set to auto (or scroll).

**Example CSS**

```
.scrollDiv {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**Example HTML**

```
<div class="scrollDiv">
  <!-- rest of ccDoc goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Should I add after the <xp:this.data>...</xp:this.data> ?

Comment: Yes, add it where your content starts

Comment: Both scrollbars are showing: the cc scroll bar and the full window browser scrollbar

Comment: So now your ccDoc scrolls as expected but the browser window has a scrollbar too? The browser scrollbar appears because your other content is higher than the browser window. So check your min-height and height CSS attributes for your other content

Comment: the other control meaning, the cc which contains all the cc's?

Comment: You need to check your CSS. I can recommend using Chrome and the Inspect Element feature. Can you confirm that your ccDoc now scrolls as expected?

Comment: I just made a simple example and scrolling of content within a div in an XPage works as expected (setting height to 250px and overflow to auto). It will be difficult to help you further without seeing the output of your code.

Comment: In my main custom control which contains all the others custom controls, there isn't any CSS. Even i added 10px in the scrollDiv sheet, the size of the cc is not different and the window full scrollbar appears.

Comment: Your output in the browser contains CSS. You need to check what affects the height of the new div (for instance using Chrome Developer Tools).